# On dropdown search not able to generate pop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "iifl_conference";
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_ConferenceLayout.cshtml";
}
@model IIFLWeb.Models.Parents.EventsParent
@section Conference
{
    <div class="search-ac-list">
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlSpeaker", Model.lstSpeakerData, "Select Speaker", new { @onchange = "GetSearchedSpeakerData(this)", @class = "select2" })
    </div>
}
```

The Main issue is that I am not able to generate pop up in search

```
function GetSearchedSpeakerData(val) {
    var selectedSpeaker = val.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/NewConference/getSearchedSpeaker",
        data: {"name": selectedSpeaker },
        success: function (result) {
            var SpeakData = '';
            $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                var SpeakerName = '';
                SpeakData += ' <li>';
                SpeakData += '<a href="#SpeakerPopup"  onclick="GetSelectedSpeakerData(\'' + val.Name + '\');" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in" id="SpeakerDetails" class="open-popup-link popup-block">';
                SpeakData += '<div class="height240">';
                SpeakData += '<div class="circle-img">';
                if(val.Name=="Panel Discussions")
                {
                    SpeakData += ' <img src="../../Upload/SpecialistSpeaker/' + val.ImageUrl + ' " alt="Panel Discussions "/>';

                }
                else 
                {
                    SpeakData += ' <img src="../../Upload/SpecialistSpeaker/' + val.ImageUrl + ' " alt="'+val.Name+'"/>';
                }
                SpeakData += '</div>';
                SpeakData += '<h4>'+val.Title +'</h4>';
                SpeakData += '<label class="speaker-date">';
                SpeakData += +val.TimeSlot + ", " + val.Venue  + " at "+val.SpeakerDate ;
                SpeakData += ' </label>';
                SpeakData += '</div>';
                SpeakData += '<div class="speaker-bx">';
                SpeakData += '<h3 id="SpeakerName">' + val.Name + '</h3>';
                SpeakData += '<h4>' + val.Designation + '</h4>';
                SpeakData += '</div>';
                SpeakData += '</a>';
                SpeakData += '</li>';               
            });
            $("#UlProfileList ").empty();
            $("#UlProfileList").append(SpeakData);
        }
    });
}
```

I am getting name from `dropdownlist` and from  Ajax function name called `GetSearchedSpeakerData(val)` and I get that particular `div`

Now `OnClick` of that particular Div Need to generate Popup, for that I am using another Ajax function name called `GetSelectedSpeakerData(val)` , This function is create so that on select of the particular `div` I get  "name" value on that name value is and popup is  created form ajax function `GetSelectedSpeakerData(val)`..

```
function GetSelectedSpeakerData(val) {  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/NewConference/getSearchedSpeaker",
        data: { "name": val },
        success: function (result) {
            var SpeakData = '';
            var Speaktopic='';
            var Speaktab='';
            $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                var SpeakerName = '' ;
                SpeakData += ' <div class="col-sm-3">';
                SpeakData += ' <div class="circle-img">';
                SpeakData += ' <img src="../../Upload/SpecialistSpeaker/'+ val.ImageUrl+ ' " alt=" '+val.Name+ '"/>';
                SpeakData += '</div>';
                SpeakData += '</div>';
                SpeakData += '<div class="col-sm-9">';
                if(val.Name=="Panel Discussions")
                {
                    SpeakData += '<h3>Panel Discussion</h3>';
                }
                else
                {
                    SpeakData += '<h3>'+val.Name+'</h3>';
                }
                SpeakData += '<h5>'+val.Designation+'</h5>';
                SpeakData += '<h4>' + val.Title + '</h4>';
                if(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.IsVenue)) == true)
                {
                    SpeakData += '<label class="speaker-date"> ( ' + val.SpeakerDate + ", " + val.TimeSlot + " at " + val.Venue + ')</label>';
                }
                SpeakData +='</div>';
                Speaktopic += '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1-1">' + val.Description + '</div>';
                Speaktopic += '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab1-2">' + val.CompanyDesc + '</div>';
                Speaktopic += '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab1-3">';
                Speaktopic += '<h4>' + val.Title + '</h4>';
                Speaktopic += val.Topic +'</div>';
                Speaktopic += '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab1-4">';
                Speaktopic += '<video controls class="VideoPlayer">';
                Speaktopic +='<source src="http://www.iiflcap.com/IPad/Conference/Videos/2017/'+val.VideoUrl+'"  type="video/mp4"></video></div>';
                if (val.Description != "")
                {
                    Speaktab += '<li role="presentation" class="active">';
                    Speaktab +=' <a href="#Tab1-1" aria-controls="Tab1-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>';
                    Speaktab +=' </li>';
                }
                if (val.CompanyDesc != "")
                {
                    Speaktab +='<li role="presentation" >';
                    Speaktab +=' <a href="#Tab1-2" aria-controls="Tab1-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>';
                    Speaktab +='  </li>';
                }
                if(val.Topic != "")
                {
                    Speaktab +='  <li role="presentation">';
                    Speaktab +='<a href="#Tab1-3" aria-controls="Tab1-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Topic</a></li>';
                    Speaktab +='</li>';
                }
                if(val.VideoUrl != "")
                {
                    Speaktab +='  <li role="presentation">';
                    Speaktab +=  '<a href="#Tab1-4" aria-controls="Tab1-4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Video</a></li>';
                    Speaktab += '</li>';
                }
            });
            $("#Details").empty();
            $("#Details").append(SpeakData);
            $("#Tabcontent").empty();
            $("#Tabcontent").append(Speaktopic);
            $("#Menutabs").empty();
            $("#Menutabs").append(Speaktab);
         }
    });
}
```

I can see on the brower the popup div called div is named as #SpeakerPopup
But I cannot  see the Popup up

```
<div id="SpeakerPopup" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide">
    <div id = "Details" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="circle-img">
                <img src="resources/images/speakers/1.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h3>Dr. Jim Walker</h3>
            <h5>Renowned economist, Founder and Managing Director, Asianomic</h5>
            <h4>"World War Three"</h4>
            <label class="speaker-date">(Tuesday, 21 February, 8:30am at Golconda)</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">            
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <ul id="Menutabs" class="nav nav-tabs Border-0 popuptabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#Tab1-1" aria-controls="Tab1-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Tab1-2" aria-controls="Tab1-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Company</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#Tab1-3" aria-controls="Tab1-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Topic</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#Tab1-4" aria-controls="Tab1-4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Video</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="Tabcontent" class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1-1">
                    <p>hello </p>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab1-2">
                    <p>HEllo</p>
                </div>  
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab1-3">
                    <h4>"World War Three"</h4>
                    <p>hi </p>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab1-4">tttddd
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is purely `css` issue. I see `mfp-hide` class on `popup` - `div#SpeakerPopup` which basically might be having some property `display:none` in `CSS`. So what I would suggest is, Just add `$("#SpeakerPopup").show()` at the end of `GetSelectedSpeakerData(val)` `ajax-success`. Also you can just replace below lines

```
$("#Details").empty();
$("#Details").append(SpeakData);
$("#Tabcontent").empty();
$("#Tabcontent").append(Speaktopic);
$("#Menutabs").empty();
$("#Menutabs").append(Speaktab);
```

with just

```
$("#Details").html(SpeakData);
$("#Tabcontent").html(Speaktopic);
$("#Menutabs").html(Speaktab);
```

and at the end of these you can add `$("#SpeakerPopup").show()`.

**PS** - Seems like you've been using `twitter-bootstrap` framework for responsive design. If so, you can try using `bootstrap-modals` to achieve this elegantly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you . everymuch it was problem related to css itself.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. n yea.. Do upvote and mark this as answer if it helped you.. :)